# How bash eval expansion work for single qoute double qoute

Tags: bash, eval

Someone please help to explain how this work? About the single quote it should not interpret anything but it is not working as what i expected. I expect to get echo $testvar value exactly '"123b"'.

```
a="testvar"
b="'"123b"'"
eval $a='$b'
echo $testvar
'123b'


a="testvar"
b='"123b"'
eval $a='$b'
echo $testvar
"123b"

a="testvar"
b='"123b"'
eval $a=$b
echo $testvar
123b
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you want `testvar` to be `<single-quote><double-quote>123b<double-quote><single-quote>`:

```
testvar=\'\"123b\"\'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this in C or Java:

```
char* str = "123b";  
printf("%s\n", str);

String str = "123b";
System.out.println(str);
```

Why does this write `123b` when we clearly used double quotes? Why doesn't it write `"123b"`, with quotes?

The answer is that the quotes are not part of the data. The quotes are used by the programming language to determine where strings start and stop, but they're not in any way part of the string. This is just as true for Bash as for C and Java.

Just like there's no way in Java to differentiate Strings created with `"123" + "b"` and `"123b"`, there's no way in Bash to tell that `b='"123b"'` used single quotes in its definition, as opposed to e.g. `b=\"123b\"`.

If given a variable you want to assign its value surrounded by single quotes, you can use  e.g.

```
printf -v testvar "'%s'" "$b"
```

But this just adds new literal single quotes around a string. It doesn't and cannot care how `b` was originally quoted, because that information is stored.

To instead add a layer of escaping to a variable, so that when evaluated once it turns into a literal string identical to your input, you can use:

```
printf -v testvar "%q" "$b"
```

This will produce a value which is quoted equivalently but not necessarily identically to your original definition. For `"value"` (a literal with double quotes in it), it may produce `\"value\"` or `'"value"'` or `'"'value'"'` which all evaluate exactly to `"value"`.